# Syntax highlighting not working for Python in VS Code with type annotations after reformatting

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to get Visual Studio Code to format (the colours not the layout) Python code with type annotations (hinting). It's failing to do so for the following code:

```
from typing import Iterator

# return math.factorial(x)
def fib(n: int) -> Iterator[int]:
    a, b = 0, 1
    while a < n:
        yield a
        a, b = b, a + b        

"""
This function checks whether a string is a palindrome.
s - The string to check.
"""
def is_palindrome(s: str) -> bool:
    return s == s[::-1]

"""
This function compares two strings of word letters and returns the percentage match.

p_string1 - The first letters to compare.
p_string2 - The second letters to compare.
"""
def compare_letters(p_string1: str, p_string2: str) -> float:
    return 1.0
```

I'm using `"python.formatting.provider": "black"` but I also tried `autopep8` and `yapf`. They all seem to fail in the same way, by getting it all mixed up after the type annotations.

When I go to the `black` website and paste the code into the Black Playground it works fine though.

I have upgraded using `python -m pip install --upgrade black` and it is showing the same version (black-19.10b0) as the Black Playground, so not sure where this is Visual Studio Code issue or a me issue.

I am using `WinPython 3.7.1 (v3.7.1:260ec2c36a, Oct 20 2018, 14:57:15) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32`.

Not really sure what to log a bug against with all this linting, formatting (colour/layout), Python parsing, etc.

Has anyone had any success with formatting Python type annotations in Visual Studio Code and what settings are you using?

UPDATE: This does not happen when I run with `code --disable-extensions`. Does anyone know how I can disable extensions selectively in order to find out which one is causing the issue?

Comment: What are you expecting the result to be? Other than having the docstrings in the wrong spot (they should be under the `def` line and indented in a level), I don't see anything improperly formatted.

Comment: Just paste it into VSC and you'll see all the colours come out wrong, even after correcting the docstrings.

Comment: Syntax highlighting looks fine to me based on the example code above. Could be more specific by what you mean with "fail in the same way"? What is the failure you're seeing? I just ran your code in VS Code with the Python extension using Black and it reformatted it appropriately.

Comment: After `Iterator[int]:` everything is pretty much white except for the occasional 2 colours. Keywords like `while`, `yield`, `def` and `return` aren't blue as they should be. `docstrings` aren't gray. `comments` aren't green, etc. Can you share what settings you are using?

Comment: I've updated your title to be a bit more explanatory. Basically syntax highlighting is a VS Code thing, not an extension thing. I would try changing your theme and see if that leads to a different output as they all choose what they want to highlight and they don't all agree on what's important.

Comment: Tried several themes as per your suggestion, they all have the same issue.

Comment: Turns out the issue does not occur when I run with `code --disable-extensions`. How can I selectively turn off extensions to find out which one is causing the issue?

Comment: Disabling the One Dark Pro theme extension fixed the issue briefly, but after uninstalling it and restarting the issue was back.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Uninstalling the `Python for VSCode` extension fixed the issue.

Comment: This didn't totally work for me. I had to uninstall all python extensions and then install the "Python Extension Pack". Hopefully this works for someone else.

Comment: You are a savior! Didn't think the answer would be so simple :)

Comment: For my case, nothing was wrong with the config or vscode extensions. I simply switched the VScode colour theme from `Dark (Visual Studio)` to `Dark Modern`

Answer (score -1):

This may be overkill, but I solved this problem on Linux Mint like this:

```
sudo apt purge code
sudo apt autoremove
rm -fR ~/.config/Code
sudo apt install code
```

Then I installed the [PyLance extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.vscode-pylance) for rich highlighting.