# VSCode python syntax highlighting having some problems

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am using vs code with microsoft extension to program in python but whenever I declare the return type of a function the syntax highlighting stops working from that line. [Image with exemple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6Z9Z.png)

Comment: try to cut and paste the whole text again

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Syntax highlighting not working for Python in VS Code with type annotations after reformatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59342329/syntax-highlighting-not-working-for-python-in-vs-code-with-type-annotations-afte)

Answer (score 2):

The highlighting was provided by the extension.

Built-in: `Python Language Basics`:

[image]

Or you can install the `MagicPython` extension.

So, it looks like you have some problem with these extensions or some other extension disturb their work.

Try to disable and enable these extensions to find out which one caused it, then you can reinstall them. If you want to reinstall the built-in extension you can try to reinstall the VSCode.

And the Theme can modify the color, could you try to switch to some other `Color Theme`? Such as `SynthWave '84`.

Comment: @JohnSnowz33 hope to hear from you.